# Подключение к базе данных в Phpshtorm

Tags: mysql, docker, phpstorm

Есть файл `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  mysql1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/config/mysql/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
      MYSQL_USER: root
```

В файле `init.sql` находится скрипт создания бд `dev`. Запускаю контейнеры, все нормально поднимается. После этого в phpshtorm пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных во вкладке `database`.Указываю такие данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но получаю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в самом приложение к базе подключается нормально и все работает

Answer (score 1):

`HOST:CONTAINER`, 33066 попробуйте